# I want if there are 2 elements with same text one Is removed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make when the user chooses an option It's text be in another paragraph

I want If the user chose the same option twice It's text doesn't copy in the paragraph again

```js
$('.cho-skills').on('change', function() {

  $('.al-skils').append($('.formss .bio .append-p .eac-p').clone(true).removeClass('disp-no'));

  $('.formss .bio .each-sk').last().text($('.cho-skills').val());

});

$('.formss .bio .eac-p i').on('click', function() {

  $(this).parents('.eac-p').remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-inp cho-skills">
  <option value="1">Choose your skills *</option>
  <option>skill 1</option>
  <option>skill 2</option>
  <option>skill 3</option>
</select>

<div class="skil-inbio">
  <div class="al-skils">
    <div class="append-p disp-no">

      <div class="eac-p">
        <p class="each-sk"></p>
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. The user selects an option and the value of your `option` gets copied into a `p`?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing, but I want If The user chose the same option twice nothing happen @Aaron3219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the info where to append the `p` elements so in my example I appended them in `.eac-p`. You should be able to configure it to your needs.

```js
$('.cho-skills').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(!$('.eac-p > p:contains("'+val+'")').length) {
   $(".eac-p").append("<p>" + val + "</p>");
  }
})

$(document).on("click", ".eac-p > p", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-inp cho-skills">
  <option value="1">Choose your skills *</option>
  <option>skill 1</option>
  <option>skill 2</option>
  <option>skill 3</option>
</select>

<div class="skil-inbio">
  <div class="al-skils">
    <div class="append-p disp-no">

      <div class="eac-p">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Let's go trough this:

1. You set an  `onchange` event listener.
2. `var val` is the value of your `option`.
3. Next we check if an element already exists. To do this we use a CSS pseudo class `:contains`. JQuery will return an array of all elements that contain the value (`$('.eac-p > p:contains("'+val+'")')`). If the array is empty no elements were found, but if there is one element it will return the elements. So let's check the `length` to see if an element was found (`$('.eac-p > p:contains("'+val+'")').length`)
4. Remember: `0` equals `false`! Do you see the `!`? This is similar to using `== false`. You could therefore also write `$('.eac-p > p:contains("'+val+'")').length == false`. But it doesn't really matter.
5. So if the array is empty and no element was found, the function will append your `p`.
6. The rest of the code is for removing the `p` after it was clicked.

### Edit

```js
$('.cho-skills').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (!$('.eac-p > p:contains("' + val + '")').length) {
    var temp = $(".append-p.disp-no").clone();
    temp.removeClass("disp-no").find("p").text(val);

    $(".al-skils").append(temp);
  }
})

$(document).on("click", ".append-p .eac-p > p", function() {
  $(this).closest(".append-p").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-inp cho-skills">
  <option value="1">Choose your skills *</option>
  <option>skill 1</option>
  <option>skill 2</option>
  <option>skill 3</option>
</select>

<div class="skil-inbio">
  <div class="al-skils">
    <div class="append-p disp-no">

      <div class="eac-p">
        <p class="each-sk"></p>
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

In this edit we use a different method. We clone the element and set it as a variable. Important: The variable **isn't** actually this element:

```
<div class="append-p disp-no">
  <div class="eac-p">
     <p class="each-sk"></p>
     <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

The variable is a complete new element that isn't yet appended.
We then change to our needs and append it.

Comment: I want to append the div that has class eac-p and the p inside it has the calue of the option selected. I want to append it in the div that has the class al-skils.So your code isn't working with it.

Comment: I will make an edit shortly and notify you. However, stackoverflow is not a service provider, where you get your code snippets ready to go. My answer at this state should give you a general idea of how to do it and you should be able to configure it to your needs by putting some effort in it. If you have problems in this process you can ask again of course.

Comment: I know that but your code depends on appending the HTML code for the p not calling its class while I need to append the div that has other elements in it and If I can do that or appending the HTML code with alot of elements I won't be asking the question from the first place

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer @IbrahimYousry